# Update operation with substring in MSSQL

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I have the below table in my MSSQL.

```
itemNo        itemDesc                 ComponentType    Voltage
100001LF    CAP CER 10n 25V 20% 0805    CAPACITOR   NULL
100002LF    CAP CER 10n 50V 20% 1206    CAPACITOR   NULL
100008LF    CAP CER 100n 25V 20% 0805   CAPACITOR   NULL
100012LF    CAP CERAM 1n 25V 20% 0805   CAPACITOR   NULL
100013LF    CAP CER 100n 25V 20% 0805   CAPACITOR   NULL
```

Now, how to determine the voltage from `itemDesc` and put it in to the Voltage ?

***Note: The voltage can be determined like this: Search for the letter `V`, take all characters before you see a whitespace.***

My initial attempt is this: [But, did not work :( ]

```
UPDATE dbo.capacitor

SET [Voltage] = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('% ', ItemDesc) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(itemDesc, CHARINDEX['V ', ItemDesc], CHARINDEX['V ',ItemDesc]+2)
                      ELSE null
END
```

(I am using C# for the coding stuff. But, I wish this operation can be done with in SQL Server itself instead of using C# to take each record , process and put it back).

Comment: What happens if the `'CAP CER'` portion happens to contact a `'V'`?  Or can you ***guarantee*** that's not possible?  Or are any other searches possible?  Such as `3rd from last item in a space separated list`?

Comment: @MatBailie: Ya, i can guarantee that never happens because It is me who takes responsibility for putting data. So, it always `follows a standard pattern`. :)

Comment: I don't have time to give you a solution, but here's my hint...  After you've found the first `'V'`, take everything up to that `'V'` and reverse the string.  Now find everything up to the first `' '` and you'll have found the voltage, backwards, so just reverse it again.

Comment: @MatBailie: Thanks for the hint. But, the problem is that in the code sample provided above, I tried a method. But, could not get the correct syntax. Thats the problem Mat

Comment: Try `CharIndex` with `(`'s, it's not an array, it's just a regular scalar function.  Also, please include your error messages ;)

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed. is voltage always of 2 digit?

Comment: What it should return ? 25V, 50V etc... ?

Comment: @SpiderCode: just the value. `25` or `50`. And no it's not a 2 digit

Comment: @MatBailie: Ya, you are right. I was using `[` for `CharIndex` like an array but the actual syntax is `(`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE dbo.capacitor
SET [Voltage] = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('% ', itemDesc) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(itemDesc, CHARINDEX('n', itemDesc) + 1, CHARINDEX('V ',itemDesc) - (CHARINDEX('n', itemDesc) + 1))
ELSE null END 
END
```

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed. The capacity does not always end with an `'n'`, at least one is showing a `'p'` for example.

Comment: @MatBailie: nice catch. But that's an typo over-there. It always ends with 'n'. Fixed in the question :)

Answer (score 3):

I guess that would be much easier in C# but here's a solution that will work in SQL. It reverses the string and looks for V after a space and takes everything up to the next space and then reverses it back.

```
declare @desc as varchar(100) = 'CAP CER 10n 25V 20% 0805'

select REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@desc),
    charindex(' V', REVERSE(@desc)) + 2,
    CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(@desc), charindex(' V', REVERSE(@desc)) + 1) - charindex(' V', REVERSE(@desc)) - 2))
```

Comment: It works like a charm. But, any directions for me to automatically take each `itemDesc` column, process this logic and push to the `value` column ? What should I use? `Stored procedures` ?

Comment: You can use a stored proc but if it's a one off thing, you can just run it. The syntax will be like `update capacitor set value = <the above query on itemDesc column>'

Comment: The above answer is definetely great , but I am accepting the other answer because of the question (the other one matches the question). But, the above solution is effective and great. I am using the stored procedure part in my coding :) Thanks.